# Azure WebApp not starting: An error occurred while starting the application. Loading profile failed

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core 1.1.1 web application that runs properly from IIS Express. After I deploy it to Azure the web app cannot start. I get the following error:

An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Framework X86 v4.0.30319.42000    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.1.1    |    Microsoft Windows 6.2.9200

I have removed almost everything from Startup.cs and turned on all the debugging possibilities I know about. The only errors I can get is in eventlog.xml:

```
Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\logs\stdout_6624_201732620236.log, ErrorCode = -2147024893.

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed.  Failed trying to receive from out of process a request to attach a profiler.  HRESULT: 0x8007006d.
```

I assume it is some permission problem, but I have no idea where and how to set permissions on Azure file system.

Please help me, I am pulling my hair out. I am sitting here for hours solving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Including this as a reference, might be of help. https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/215   Search that page for `2147024893` for the comments relevant to your issue.

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself and I hope this solution might help someone.

The problem was with configuration of external authentication providers. As it was suggested I set the app secrets by using the Secret Manager Tool, however I did not set up the variables after deployment to Azure.

I think it is somehow misleading that there is a Authentication / Authorization section on Azure Web App Settings. I set the secrets there properly. I only realized afterwards, that the settings should be at the Application settings section as regular App setting key value pairs.